# How to use variables with the Terraform templatefile function

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

How can I use the map(string) `"principals" = local.principals`  in role.json to substitute the number value for `"aws:SourceAccount": "11051234"`

To substitute the number value for `"aws:SourceAccount": "11051234"` in the role.json file with the corresponding value from the principals map. I used `${local.principals.key}` as principals is a local value and not a variable,
I need to replace the `serviceaccount: "12434.."`  with variable.

```
locals {

 
principals = {
   ad-cloud-sandbox-env = "11051234"
   dev  = "123456788"
   prod  = "78900001"

}
output "template" {
    value = templatefile("${path.module}/test.tmpl",
    {
      "principals" = local.principals
      
      
    })  
}
```

role.json

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "scheduler.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceAccount": "11051234"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: "i used ${local.principals.key} as principals is a local value and not a variable"  - please add that code. You haven't provided any code containing `${local.principals.key}` nor you explained why it does not work.

Comment: I also have variables.tf and a test.tmpl and if i  hardcode the aws:SourceAccount ,  and try terraform apply . it outputs the map(string) values . My question is how to substitute the aws:SourceAccount with varaible. Below are the 2 files :variables.tf

variable "principals" {
  description = "(Required) list of AWS Accounts"
  type        = map(string)
  default = {
    "cloud-sandbox-env" = "11051234"
  }
}

test.tmpl
%{ for principals_key, principals_value in principals }
set ${principals_key} = ${principals_value}
%{ endfor ~}

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the specific value you want to use into the template, instead of passing the full map of values:

```
    value = templatefile("${path.module}/test.tmpl",
    {
      "accountId" = local.principals["ad-cloud-sandbox-env"]
    })
```

Then in your template file:

```
    "aws:SourceAccount": "${accountId}"
```

---

You could also create this policy JSON with an `aws_iam_policy_document` [data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document) instead of a template file.